# Checking if a json object's name is equal to something

Tags: php, json

So I have a basic json file:

```
{
    "User1": {
        "id": 1,
        ....
    },
    "User2": {
        "id": 3
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to get all the names of the users (i.e. "User1" or "User2") and check if a name entered by a user is equal to one of those names.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
foreach($this->blackList as $user) {
    if($user == $username)
        return "TRUE";
    }
    return "FALSE";
}
```

Comment: you could dump the json object using var_dump, so you can see the structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to loop at all:

```
return array_key_exists($username, $this->blackList);
```

Or if you have `json_decoded` to an object instead of an array:

```
return property_exists($this->blackList, $username);
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than the previous answer?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by efficient. In terms of execution time or memory usage, I'm not sure. In terms of having less code, yes.

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with the other answer. I was just offering an alternate approach.

Comment: I'm gonna stick to your answer because it's much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $this->blackList is decoded your json string. If yes, then code should look like this:

```
foreach($this->blackList as $blackName => $user) {
    if($blackName == $username)
        return true;
    }

}
return false;
```

Comment: So if it works perfectly then please mark my answer as finished :)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thx for info :)